# Best way to accept a generic method argument

Tags: c#, generics, methods, interface, repository

I got a interface which describes a way to do some action on some item which is looked up in some repository.

And i see two ways to create that interface.

```
public interface IService<T> where T : class
{
    void Action<TSource>(int id, TSource source, Action<T> action)
        where TSource : IRead<T>;
}
```

versus

```
public interface IService<T> where T : class
{
    void Action(int id, IRead<T> source, Action<T> action);
}
```

So, which one is the best and why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What is the problem? The answer completely depends on your problem.

Comment: What's the difference **for you**? If you don't need the "class" constrain (so you can accept value types) then they're equivalent.

Comment: There is no actual issues. Yet. I am asking, as usual, beforehand to avoid issues in a future and have more complete knowledge of C#.

Comment: ... the times where you design everything up front and don't change no matter what are long gone ... nowadays you do only as much design up front as is needed, heed YAGNI (you ain't gonna need it), KISS (keep it simple stupid) and work agile and 'embrace' (well ... not really embrace but expect) change ... so don't worry and take the simpler second version

Comment: I think this is a legitimate design question, even without a particular scenario in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go out on a limb, here, and say that the second one is better.

The first definition would allow you to use TSource directly (and not through the interface IRead that it's bound to implement) in your implementation of Action. Now, the only good use I can imagine for that would be using TSource in the signature of your function, which you're not doing. i.e. something like:

```
TSource MyAction<TSource>(int id, TSource source, Action<T, TSource> action)
        where TSource : IRead<T>; // TSource is now also returned from our method
```

In any other case, it would be much better for the body of MyAction (note that I took the liberty to rename your example method not to conflict with System.Action) to only know and use the IRead interface.